# In Racket's class system, what do augment, overment, augride, etc. do?

Tags: class, oop, racket

Racket's documentation only partially describe what `augment` and `pubment` do: `augment` makes a method that executes after the superclass's version of that method, while `pubment` makes a method that will implicitly have the `augment` property if it is defined in a child class.

The docs say absolutely nothing about `overment` and `augride`, and I can't guess what they would do based on their names. What are they, and what is the difference between them?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The relatively large family of inheritance functions for Racket's class system is, as you describe, a little confusing, and their somewhat cutesy names don't always help.

In order to understand this, Racket provides two separate mechanisms for method inheritance.

- **`public`** methods correspond to the classical idea of public methods in other OO models. Methods declared with `public` may be overridden in subclasses, unless they're declared *final*, in which case they cannot.
- **`pubment`** methods are similar, but they cannot be *overridden*, only *augmented*. Augmenting a method is similar to overriding it, but the dispatch calls the superclass's implementation instead of the subclass's.

To clarify the difference between overriding and augmentation, when an overridden method is called, the overriding implementation is executed, which may *optionally* call the superclass's implementation via `inherit/super`. In contrast, in an augmented method, the superclass's implementation receives control, and it may optionally call the subclass's implementation via `inner`.

Now, we're also provided **`public-final`**, **`override-final`**, and **`augment-final`**. These are pretty simple. Declaring a method with `public-final` means it can neither be augmented nor overridden. Using `override-final` overrides a superclass's public method, but it doesn't allow any *further* overriding. Finally, `augment-final` is similar, but for methods declared with `pubment`, not `public`.

So then, what about the two weird hybrids, `overment` and `augride`?

- **`overment`** can be used to implement methods *initially defined* with `public`. This "converts" them to augmentable methods instead of overridable methods for all the class's subclasses.
- **`augride`** goes in the opposite direction. It converts an augmentable method to one that is overridable, but the overriding implementations only replace the augmentation, not the original implementation.

---

To summarize:

- **`public`**, **`pubment`**, and **`public-final`** all *declare* methods that do not exist in a superclass.
- Then we have a family of forms for extending superclass methods:

  - **`override`** and **`augment`** extend methods declared with **`public`** and **`pubment`**, respectively, using the relevant behaviors.
  - **`override-final`** and **`augment-final`** do the same as their non-final counterparts, but prevent further overriding or augmentation.
  - **`overment`** and **`augride`** convert overridable methods to augmentable ones and vice-versa.

For another, fuller explanation, you might be interested in taking a look at [the paper from which Racket's model was derived](http://www.eecs.northwestern.edu/~robby/pubs/papers/oopsla2004-gff.pdf), which is quite readable and includes some helpful diagrams.

Comment: It's a shame that Racket's default class system supports final methods, though. I'm sure I'll end up having to write some nasty workaround for some final method at some point in the future.

Comment: @ThrowawayAccount3Million Having final methods is an important tool to enforce encapsulation. It shouldn't be abused, and I don't think the Racket libraries ever use it lightly.

Comment: Thanks—this is important stuff! Is it explained in the official documentation anywhere? In particular, do you know the meaning of the arguments to `augment`, or know where they're documented? (So far, I haven't been able to understand the meaning of the example [here](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/createclass.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fclass-internal..rkt%29._augment%29%29).)